# Connecting points with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I a trying to create an application that you need to connect dots to each other to form a sequence. Something similar to this game http://play-dot-to.com/. But to be able to connect each one to a random dot, not a specific one.

The problem is that i can't find a script or a source that can allow me to connect dots to each other while dragging the mouse from the start dot to the target dot. i know it can be done with java script on click, the line will appear on click, but i need it to be draggable.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) Javascript library

Based on what you are trying to accomplish I think you'll find this demo useful:
http://raphaeljs.com/curver.html

Comment: Thank you Ryan, but i did check this demo before, and in this case, the lines are already existing, so you just have to manipulate them.
what i m searching for is when you click on the starting point and you drag, a line will be shown behind you untill you reach your target, and then will stop

Answer (score 0):

The site you linked is using SVGs to draw the line. A simpler way to do it would be using [HTML5 Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API). Basically, what you need to know is that you'll be using `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `mousemove` events.

I've made a quick example for you, using HTML Canvas.

https://jsfiddle.net/qzs7bvfh/

Comment: Thank you Greg. This could help me. I'll try it .